# Extract part of a string in php

Tags: php

i have this kind of string into my db

```
http://www.mydomain.com/assets/Image/......./image.jpg
```

and would like to clean it up and make it

```
image.jpg
```

how could get the part of the string starting from the right until the first "/" ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
$url = "http://www.mydomain.com/assets/Image/......./image.jpg";
$filename = basename($url);
echo $filename;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the basename function.

```
basename('http://www.mydomain.com/assets/Image/......./image.jpg');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 echo preg_replace('~.+/~', '', $url);
```

see also parse_url, pathinfo